# Product is adding again to cart when 'add to cart' button is clicked twice

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ajax

I have been working on Magento 1.9.2.4, 
I am using an ajax cart extension to adding the product to cart, and its working good. the only problem I am having is once we click add to cart button is adding the product to cart, and if we click the button twice and so on the product keeps adding to the cart or quantity of the item in cart increases on every click on "add to cart" button,

I think it's Magento's default functionality, And I am trying to show a dialogue stating this product is already in the cart'* when the product is already added before in the cart while clicking on the "add to cart" button.

Any ideas for the function are welcomed.

Comment: This is not default magento behaviour - I think there is something wrong with the ajax cart extension.

Comment: @jscar i think it is, just checked it out on new magento setup. see magento-demo.lexiconn.com

Comment: Oh! I stand corrected. Strange thing is on my sites a double-click only adds a single item but I can't see any difference in the javascript being called to your default site.

Comment: Its not about double click. its adding product again if the button clicked again after and event is fired. Double-click just selects or highlights the button.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood 'click the button twice'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

1. Product -> Inventory -> Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
2. System -> Configuration -> Inventory -> Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

[image]

Comment: I think with this option i can not edit product quantity in cart? @raymond

Comment: Ah right --- I misunderstood.

Apologies.